# Pressure sensor milibar value decrease when milk temperature is decrease from 20 to 4 C

Tags: physics, sensors, pressure

our application is measure the tank Level using pressure sensor.then we convert the level to qty.

our problem is 
temperature is decrease from 20 C to 4 C pressure level is also decrease(About 10 MM ).

we used following formula for Pressure to Level conversion

L = P / (ρ x g)

ρ = ρ0 x SG

ρ0 = Density of liquid (1000)

SG = 1.033 (at 4 C)

(we used density of milk = 1.003073 - 0.000179t - 0.000368F + 0.00374N)

where t = temperature in degrees C; F = percent fat; and N = percent nonfat 
solids(SNF)

g  = 9.80665 ms-2

Answer (score 1):

Since you want for the application you want to design, that pressure do not change with the temperature changes, you can use the following sensors:
https://www.controleverything.com/content/Analog-Digital-Converters?sku=MS5637-02BA03_I2CS
https://www.controleverything.com/content/Pressure?sku=AMS5812_I2CS_0150-D-B
These sensors would require I2C interface with the controlling unit you are using.
If you will give me any idea about the controlling unit you are using I can further provide you with the codes and all.
I hope this helps you out.